# Transfer trained machine learning model

Tags: ibm-q-experience, machine-learning

I know just the basics of quantum computer i.e. superposition, entanglement, gates and few other kinds of stuff.

Now the question is it possible to transfer a trained machine learning model from IBM Q(don't much about quantum algorithms) to AWS, GCP or Azure?

If yes will it have the same accuracy that we get IBM Q?

If yes how to do that?

Comment: Could we get clarification on the QML model type used?